# C++: Calculate acceleration value from 2 complement

Tags: c++, sensors

I'm switching from the Arduino IDE to ESP IDF and I want to test an accelerometer (LIS2DW12). Initially, I had problems with the hardware-related programming. In the meantime I'm getting good values, but I need a factor of 10 for this. It`s a 14 bit value, stored in 2 8bit registers.
I've searched some forums and have been working on it for a few days. But I haven't been able to find out, why I'm wrong by a factor of 10.
What am I doing wrong? I am grateful for any reference!
[Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhCu.jpg)
[LIS2DW12 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/lis2dw12.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "string.h"

static const char *TAG = "LIS2DW12: ";

#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO           22             /*!< GPIO number used for I2C master clock */
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO           21             /*!< GPIO number used for I2C master data  */
#define I2C_MASTER_NUM              1              /*!< I2C master i2c port number, the number of i2c peripheral interfaces available will depend on the chip */
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ          400000         /*!< I2C master clock frequency */
#define I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE   0              /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE   0              /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS       1000


// Sensor Reg
#define SENSOR_ADDR                 0x19        /*!< Slave address of the MPU9250 sensor */
#define WHO_AM_I_REG_ADDR           0x0F        /*!< Register addresses of the "who am I" register */

#define Temp_L 0x0D
#define Temp_H 0x0E
#define WhoAmI 0x0F
#define CTRL1  0x20
#define CTRL2  0x21
#define CTRL3  0x22
#define CTRL4  0x23
#define CTRL5  0x24
#define CTRL6  0x25

#define X_LSB 0x28
#define X_MSB 0x29
#define Y_LSB 0x2A
#define Y_MSB 0x2B
#define Z_LSB 0x2C
#define Z_MSB 0x2D

uint16_t X_raw, Y_raw, Z_raw;
float X, Y, Z;
int ix,iy,iz;

void Sensor_data_test(){
    
    byte buf[2];
    
    // read register
    register_read(Z_LSB, buf, 2);

    Z_raw = buf[1]<<8 | buf[0];        // buf = MSB <<8 | LSB;

    // print buffer
    Serial.println("Sensor Data:");   
    Serial.print("buf0: ");Serial.print(buf[0]); 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("buf1: ");Serial.print(buf[1]); 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Z uint16_t : ");Serial.print(Z_raw); 
    Serial.println();

    // calculate binary and print
    uint16_t Zh = Z_raw;
    String hz;
    while(Zh!=0) 
    {
        hz=(Zh%2==0 ?"0":"1")+hz; 
        Zh/=2; 
    }
    Serial.print("Z bin : ");Serial.println(hz); 


    //calculate 2'er complement
    int k = 0;
    if(Z_raw & (((uint16_t)0x1) << 15))     //check if binary is negativ
    {                                       //if negativ, do
        Z_raw = ~Z_raw;                     //invert bits
        Z_raw = Z_raw + 1;                  //add one bit
        Z_raw = Z_raw >> 2;                 //shift 2 spaces to the rigt (caused by Sensor register)          
        k = Z_raw * -1;                     //save as Integer an reverse sign
    }
    else{                                   //if positiv, do
        Z_raw = Z_raw >> 2;                 //shift to spaces to the rigt (caused by Sensor register)
        k = Z_raw;                          //save as Integer
    }

    if (k){ 
        Serial.print("Z int: ");Serial.print(k); 
        Serial.println();
    }

    //acceleration value ============================================

    Z= (float)k *16/8191;   // factor 10 needed?

    Serial.print("Z accel: ");Serial.print(Z); 
    Serial.println();

}

void Set_Sensor_Config(){
    register_write_byte(CTRL1,0x55);
    register_write_byte(CTRL2,0x04);
    register_write_byte(CTRL3,0x00);
    register_write_byte(CTRL4,0x00);
    register_write_byte(CTRL5,0x00);
    register_write_byte(CTRL6,0x34);
}

void Show_Sensor_Config(){
    uint8_t buf[1];
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "LIS12DW Config: ");
    register_read(CTRL1, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL1 = %X", buf[0]);
    register_read(CTRL2, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL2 = %X", buf[0]);
    register_read(CTRL3, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL3 = %X", buf[0]);
    register_read(CTRL4, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL4 = %X", buf[0]);
    register_read(CTRL5, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL5 = %X", buf[0]);
    register_read(CTRL6, buf, 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CTRL6 = %X", buf[0]);
}

extern "C" void app_main()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_init());
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "I2C initialized successfully");

    Set_Sensor_Config();
    Show_Sensor_Config();

    Sensor_data_test();

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_driver_delete(I2C_MASTER_NUM));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "I2C de-initialized successfully");
    
    
}
```

Output:

```
I (336) LIS2DW12: : LIS12DW Config: 
I (336) LIS2DW12: : CTRL1 = 55
I (337) LIS2DW12: : CTRL2 = 4
I (341) LIS2DW12: : CTRL3 = 0
I (344) LIS2DW12: : CTRL4 = 0
I (348) LIS2DW12: : CTRL5 = 0
I (351) LIS2DW12: : CTRL6 = 34
Sensor Data:
buf0: 40
buf1: 248
Z uint16_t : 63528
Z bin : 1111100000101000
Z int: -502
Z accel: -0.98
I (367) LIS2DW12: : I2C de-initialized successfully
```

I wrote a function that reads out the Z acceleration registers and converts the data into a value [m/s²]. I expect a value of about 9.81 but I get 0.98 (acceleration of gravity).

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I set the range to 16g. And the resolution are 13bit (8191).

```
Z= (float)k *16/8191;   // factor 10 needed?
```

Comment: According to the datasheet the resolution is 14 bits, but you spend a bit encoding the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to write that it still doesn't work. But while I was trying to write my questions and formatting my code, I found my mistake. Thanks to deviantgeek for your help. I followed the sample code and finally got it to work.

You cannot/should not approach the matter manually. Because even I can't understand the factors yet. If someone gets an incorrect value, then look at this function "lis2dw12_from_fs2_to_mg". There are various factors that depend, for example, on the range (2g, 4g,...)
I used this code as "template": [lis2dw12_read_data_single.c](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/blob/master/lis2dw12_STdC/examples/lis2dw12_read_data_single.c)

This code works for 16g. It meassures only Z, but the other directions are the same

```
int32_t accel_z_raw_get(int16_t *val)
{
    uint8_t buff[2];
    int32_t ret;
    if(STATUS & 0x01){     //check if Data ready to read // #define STATUS 0x27

        ret = register_read(Z_LSB, buff, 2);
        *val = (int16_t)buff[1];
        *val = (*val * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
      }
      return ret;
}

float_t lis2dw12_from_fs2_lp1_to_mg(int16_t lsb)
{
  return ((float_t)lsb) * 0.488f;
}

static int16_t data_raw_z[1];
static float accel_z_mg[1];

void get_sensor_data(){

    char str[25];

    accel_z_raw_get(data_raw_z);

    accel_z_mg[0] = lis2dw12_from_fs2_lp1_to_mg(data_raw_z[0]);

    sprintf((char *)str, "acceleration Z: % 4.2f\t\r\n", accel_z_mg[0]);

    puts(str);

}

extern "C" void app_main()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_init());
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "I2C initialized successfully");

    Set_Sensor_Config();
    
    Show_Sensor_Config();

    get_sensor_data();

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_driver_delete(I2C_MASTER_NUM));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "I2C de-initialized successfully");
}
```

The output is: -981.86 That´s correct, because the sensor measures in mg`s.
The negativ sign is ok, caus the sensor is upsidedown...

```
I (336) LIS2DW12-Register: LIS12DW Config: 
I (336) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL1 = 55
I (338) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL2 = 4
I (342) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL3 = 0
I (347) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL4 = 0
I (351) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL5 = 0
I (355) LIS2DW12-Register: CTRL6 = 34
I (359) LIS2DW12-Register: STATUS = 1
acceleration Z: -981.86
```

Thank you for your help! This forum is great!

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says that all measurements are in micro-g's, so I wonder if your 0.98 reading is 0.98g, or 9.61m/s².

Comment: Hey Botje, thanks for the hint. I didn't find it in the data sheet, but because the example code also outputs mg's, I'm convinced. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a complete answer becuase i dont have this sensor available, but i would start by refactoring your code because it could be the way you are extracting axis values causing the final computation to fail. The registers at OUT_Z_L and OUT_Z_H tell you that they provide 8 bits each, that produce a 16 bit 2s compliment, basically int16_t. You are trying to use them as if they were uint16_t, which they are not, and manually converting them, which is always prone to errors and can definitely cause some weird behavior. its fine to use uint8_t, char, whatever to extract the register data as a buffer. but when you combine the MSB and LSB, you should use the correct type: int16_t instead.

[Here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/lis2dw12-pid/blob/master/lis2dw12_reg.c) is a git repository with driver code that STMicro wrote for this sensor, it's in C, but that is easy to convert to C++, or you could probably just use it if you want (im not a fan of STMicro code though, so i always write my own). They extract the X, Y, and Z registers via a method called `lis2dw12_acceleration_raw_get`, they get them all at once, but this should be a good reference to follow since they made the sensor. It also gives you the method for extracting the registers and getting the proper value for each register. Here is the code that I'm referring to from their repository

```
int32_t lis2dw12_acceleration_raw_get(stmdev_ctx_t *ctx, int16_t *val)
{
  uint8_t buff[6];
  int32_t ret;

  ret = lis2dw12_read_reg(ctx, LIS2DW12_OUT_X_L, buff, 6);
  val[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
  val[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
  val[1] = (int16_t)buff[3];
  val[1] = (val[1] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[2];
  val[2] = (int16_t)buff[5];
  val[2] = (val[2] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[4];

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried it as in the example, but I still don't get any plausible values. I have now done it like this: